# Leaflet + Ionic5 / Angular - Map bad Rendering -

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, leaflet, ionic5, angular12

after doing some search about it without success I come to you having known there are multiple threats about this, but as i said those haven't solved my problem.

**The problem:**

 As other people has experienced, Leaflet has some issues with map and framework pages loading.

If I resize manually the browser screen it renders correctly.

if I reload the window the map is NOT rendered.

> **Example:** [image]

As you can see there are no current errors on console that may cause this issue, so let's go to the code.

**Code:**

*I have some commented code, erased for this post, but as it is commented for the `>ionic serve` command it shouldn't affect to the execution*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.scss'],
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  serviceRequestBoundsIcon = '../../../assets/custom/map-outline.svg';
  now: Date;
  private markers: L.Marker[] = [];
  private map: L.Map;
  private iconTruck = L.icon({
    iconUrl: '../../../assets/truck-39103_1280.png',
    iconSize: [40, 20],
    iconAnchor: [20, 10],
    popupAnchor: [1, -34],
    tooltipAnchor: [16, -28],
    shadowSize: [41, 41]
  });
  private iconwatch = L.icon({
    iconUrl: '../../../assets/custom/map-outline.svg',
    iconSize: [40, 20],
    iconAnchor: [20, 10],
    popupAnchor: [1, -34],
    tooltipAnchor: [16, -28],
    shadowSize: [41, 41]
  });
  private watchSubscriber: Subscription;



  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initMap();
    console.log('oninit');
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.map.invalidateSize();
    console.log('view init');
  }

  private initMap(){

    this.map = L.map('map', {
      center: [ 49.00, 10.00 ],
      zoom: 6
    });
    const tiles = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      maxZoom: 18,
      minZoom: 3,
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    });
    tiles.addTo(this.map);
  }
```

- Here I have tried moving the `initMap()` & the `this.map.invalidateSize()` to different hooks (ngAfterViewInit, ngAfterContentInit, ngOnInit, constructor), with barely the same result, sometimes it works but at reload stops working...

This angular map component is inside the location tab page made by ionic tabs generator, the location module has no logic on it.

I have also tried the MutationObserver solution founded in a post from SO. Not used by now.

```
private renderMap(){
    const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
      console.log('init mutation');
      this.map.invalidateSize();
      observer.disconnect();
      console.log('cancel observer');
    });
    console.log('init observer');
    observer.observe(document.documentElement, {
      attributes: true,
      attributeFilter: ['class'],
      childList: false,
      characterData: false,
    });
  }
```

**Inside index.html:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"/>
```

**angular.json:**

```
  "projects": {
"app": {
  "root": "",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "projectType": "application",
  "prefix": "app",
  "schematics": {},
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "www",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": [
          {
            "glob": "**/*",
            "input": "src/assets",
            "output": "assets"
          },
          {
            "glob": "**/*.svg",
            "input": "node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/svg",
            "output": "./svg"
          },
          {
            "glob": "**/*",
            "input": "node_modules/leaflet/dist/images/",
            "output": "assets"
          },
          "src/manifest.webmanifest",
          "src/manifest.webmanifest",
          "src/manifest.webmanifest",
          "src/manifest.webmanifest"
        ],
        "styles": ["./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css", "node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css", "src/theme/variables.scss", "src/global.scss"],
        "scripts": [],
        "aot": false,
        "vendorChunk": true,
        "extractLicenses": false,
        "buildOptimizer": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "optimization": false,
        "namedChunks": true,
        "serviceWorker": true,
        "ngswConfigPath": "ngsw-config.json"
      },
```

I hope i can solve this with the community help, I do not understand what can be happening here! If more details are requested please feel free to ask for them, I'll be paying attention to this post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the moment I've been able to solve the issue adding a `setTimeout(()=>{this.map.invalidateSize();},100)`, I'm wondering if there's a better solution for this please let me know!